# TSP calculation using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, algorithm

I have the following problem. I have a set of cities and their corresponding geographical coordinates. What I want to do is to be able to calculate the shortest possible path between them in a round-trip (i.e. no particular start/end point).

I have done some research and came across a few solutions, but none of them are applicable. I found that this thing is called a TSP. There is a Google API for optimizing a route between points, but the problem is that I dont want to find a route, this for example doesnt work if you have points one in US and one in Europe, as it just tells you "no route found". I dont want a route I want just a straight line between them to make it the shortest.

I also found some HTML5 solutions using genetic algorithms for finding the shortest path between points, but there is a catch. The problem is that such algorithms take into account a set of points in a 2D plane, but obviously, if we are talking about geo coordinates, the point right on the "left" of your map is in fact right next to the point on the "right end" of the map, and they can be connected via this short route - in other words we are talking about the globe, not a plane.

Is there any way I could do this? As I said, I dont want any fancy things like route directions etc. Just something that would find the optimal/near optimal order and the distance.

I would appreciate any help or hints as to where I could find some more info or how to go about doing this, ideally if you knew about some scripts that I could try to modify and implement, either using PHP or Javascript.

Comment: Google maps provides a function that calculates the distance (following the curvature).  google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()

Comment: Please consider [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007033/leaflet-js-draw-polyline-to-nearest-point-from-a-location/19009905#19009905)

Comment: yes but that is not what I want, I want to find the shortest distance between multiple points, say I have 10 points and want to find the shortest round-trip through all of them